# как повернуть объект во круг своей оси допустим(x) в java

Tags: java

мне нужно повернуть (изображение,слой) во круг оси (x),как это сделать?я пробывал rotationaxis но у меня что то не получилось...Если можно дайте ссылку на литературу но этой теме,за-ранее спасибо! П.С я гуглил но видимо неправильно искал...

Comment: setRotationAxis() задаёт ось или набор осей, вокруг которых будет проводиться поворот элемента в JavaFX. Передаётся в этот метод трёхмерная точка с параметрами для оси x, y и z соответственно.
Задав ось поворота, можно уже вращать объект через метод setRotation().

Comment: спасибо разобрался.я думал что rotationaxis это и есть эта функция которая вращает оъбект,я недогнал что надо дописывать setRotation,спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала напишите как именно Вы храните изображение или слой , какой класс используете.
Наверное следует заглянуть в Graphics2D API , там в основном важная информация по изображениям в этом направлении.

Comment: а по абстрактнее,пример кода,мне так легче,я сам потом догоню с чего начать...можно?просто пример который демонстрирует вращение(можно даже без анимации)

Comment: @AseTry хорошо , вечером напишу . Сейчас убегаю уже...